Rails & Ahoy: No route matches [OPTIONS] "/ahoy/visits"
We have a Rails 7 app that uses Ahoy and runs on Heroku. Apparently, we occasionally have users that use the website via Google Translate.
Recently, this yields this error: No route matches [OPTIONS] "/ahoy/visits".
I understand this may be related to CORS. I've seen the recommendation to install a specific gem to be able to handle OPTIONS requests but to me it's unclear what then the implications are for security and performance or anything else.
On the other hand, I am also not sure of anny consequences if we don't handle this properly. (If there is, as a random example, a Google ranking penalty, as would be the case if one didn't have SSL/HTTPS. Or some other undesirable consequence to not handling the OPTIONS request properly.)
If anybody could shed some light on it, that would be much appreciated!
It would be nice to be able to handle Ahoy events for those Google Translate users, but they're less than a percent of our traffic, so I'm not overly concerned with that aspect. But I don't want to leave this untreated completely as it is a substantial part of our error logs.
